# nuxtjs + express, why returns html?

Tags: javascript, express, nuxt.js

I am trying to do something similar to the API, using nuxtjs + express.

in **server/index.js** file I create

```
app.get ('/ test', (req, res) => {
    res.send ({method: 'GET'})
  })
```

when contacting **localhost:3000/test**
HTML markup is returned, why is this happening?

When trying to make a request through POSTMAN, HTML is also returned

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const consola = require('consola')
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt')
const app = express()

// Import and Set Nuxt.js options
const config = require('../nuxt.config.js')
config.dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

async function start() {
  // Init Nuxt.js
  const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

  const { host, port } = nuxt.options.server

  await nuxt.ready()
  // Build only in dev mode
  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt)
    await builder.build()
  }
  app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.send({ method: 'GET' })
  })
  // Give nuxt middleware to express
  app.use(nuxt.render)

  // Listen the server
  app.listen(port, host)
  consola.ready({
    message: `Server has been started on port: http://${host}:${port}`,
    badge: true
  })
}
start()
```